# Need help joining incremental data to a fact table in an incremental manor

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

TableA

| ID | Counter | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 |
| 1 | 2 | 28 |
| 1 | 3 | 34 |
| 1 | 4 | 22 |
| 1 | 5 | 80 |
| 2 | 1 | 15 |
| 2 | 2 | 50 |
| 2 | 3 | 39 |
| 2 | 4 | 33 |
| 2 | 5 | 99 |

TableB

| StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-11 |
| 2020-01-02 | 2020-01-12 |
| 2020-01-03 | 2020-01-13 |
| 2020-01-04 | 2020-01-14 |
| 2020-01-05 | 2020-01-15 |
| 2020-01-06 | 2020-01-16 |

TableC (output)

| ID | Counter | StartDate | EndDate | Val |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-11 | 10 |
| 2 | 1 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-11 | 15 |
| 1 | 2 | 2020-01-02 | 2020-01-12 | 28 |
| 2 | 2 | 2020-01-02 | 2020-01-12 | 50 |
| 1 | 3 | 2020-01-03 | 2020-01-13 | 34 |
| 2 | 3 | 2020-01-03 | 2020-01-13 | 39 |
| 1 | 4 | 2020-01-04 | 2020-01-14 | 22 |
| 2 | 4 | 2020-01-04 | 2020-01-14 | 33 |
| 1 | 5 | 2020-01-05 | 2020-01-15 | 80 |
| 2 | 5 | 2020-01-05 | 2020-01-15 | 99 |
| 1 | 1 | 2020-01-06 | 2020-01-16 | 10 |
| 2 | 1 | 2020-01-06 | 2020-01-16 | 15 |

I am attempting to come up with some SQL to create TableC. What TableC is, it takes the data from TableB, in chronological order, and for each `ID` in tableA, it finds the next counter in the sequence, and assigns that to the Start/End date combination for that ID, and when it reaches the end of the counter, it will start back at 1.

Is something like this even possible with SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible. Try to do the following:

1. Calculate maximal value for `Counter` in `TableA` using `SELECT MAX(Counter) ...` into `max_counter`.
2. Add identifier `row_number` to each row in TableB so it will be able to find matching `Counter` value using `SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() ...`.
3. Establish relation between row number in `TableB` and `Counter` in `TableA` like this `... FROM TableB JOIN TableA ON (COALESCE(NULLIF(TableB.row_number % max_counter = 0), max_counter)) = TableA.Counter`.
4. Then gather all these queries using CTE (Common Table Expression) into one query as [official documentation shows](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#with_clause).

Answer (score 1):

Consider below approach

```
select id, counter, StartDate, EndDate, value
from tableA 
join (
  select *, mod(row_number() over(order by StartDate) - 1, 5) + 1 as counter
  from tableB
)
using (counter)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Very elegant! The best.

Comment: @asdasd32 have you tried? did it work for you?